# How to display play icon over brightcove video

Tags: video, brightcove

I want to display an icon of play on my brightcove video i didn't find any solution regarding this on brightcove site. currently my video look like this[image]

and i want my video like this [image]

Answer (score 0):

You're using the chromeless video player template, which doesn't use that convention. There are other templates available if you go into Video Cloud Studio and select "Publishing." You can also design your own look and feel using the BEML markup.

Info on templates:
http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/creating-players-publishing-module

Info on BEML:
http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/customizing-players-beml